# Can't run "rake db:create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I try to setup a postgres DB for my rails project but everytime I run the command:

```
rake db:create
```

I get the error

```
    FATAL:  role "myrole" does not existCouldn't create database for{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, 
"database"=>"web_db", "username"=>"myrole", "password"=>"password", "host"=>"localhost"}                                                            rake aborted!
```

When I login into my web_db database with the user myrole and type in \du it showsme all the roles including myrole! This role has also Superuser, create Role and createDB attributes.

I have no idea whats wrong..

Edit my database.yml

```
development:                                                                                                           
  adapter: postgresql                                                                                                  
  encoding: unicode                                                                                                    
  database: myapp_development                                                                                          
  pool: 5                                                                                                              
  username: myrole                                                                                                    
  password: password                                                                                                  
  host: localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
test:                                                                                                                  
  adapter: postgresql                                                                                                  
  encoding: unicode                                                                                                    
  database: myapp_test                                                                                                 
  pool: 5                                                                                                              
  username: myrole                                                                                                    
  password: password                                                                                                  
  host: localhost
```

Comment: That's an authentication problem on your server, meaning the user defined in `database.yml` doesn't exist.

Comment: thats not the case I have that already done that. the user defined in the database.yml is also a role in postgres with rights to create databases ...

Comment: I know you think that, but apparently the database you're connecting to says that's not the case.

Comment: So what I need to do?

Comment: Create that role, or find out what role you're supposed to be using instead and use that. `myrole` seems like a placeholder.

Comment: Thats exactly what I've done. I lopgged in as postgres -> created the user "myrole" with the password "password" and allowed him to create databases. then I opened the database.yml im my /app/config directory and changed it to what ive eddited in my main post. Then I tryed to run rake db:setup and got the error that the role does not exist

Comment: don't see `web_db` as a database name in your database.yml

Comment: When I run the command rails should generate the database given in the database.yml by itself

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with rails, try using the postgres `createdb` first with the same credentials, my guess is you will get the same error - see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-createdb.html

Comment: Try  rake db:migrate fisrt

Comment: @house9 yep even when I try to login as this user I get the same message that the role does not exist ....I try to login he asks for the password and after I typed that in I get the message fatal role xy does not exist. I dont get it I created this roe like in every tutorial and doc and everytime I want to use this role it tells me it does not exist even when the command \du shows me that role.

Comment: Can you please check the steps from this tutorial: https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/creating-a-user-with-pgadmin  or generaly can you create user and add them all privilages? Just for purpose test, I think that you need to add more than you add now.

Comment: @Nezir thanks for the tutorial I already found my mistake (Im stupid). I posted it below my main post. My problem was that I changed the user to postgres and created the role under this account. When I switched back to my working user there was no sutch role. So I had to login into psql from my active working user and create the role from there. Then everything worked fine.

Comment: Good job! You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 4):

What I did wrong:

I used su postgres to open psql and create roles.

What I had to do is to login from my user with the command:

`psql -h localhost -d web_db -U postgres or sudo -u postgres psql`

Then I had to create a role and asign rights:

```
CREATE ROLE myrole;

ALTER ROLE myrole WITH login;

ALTER ROLE myrole WITH CREATEDB;

ALTER ROLE myrole WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

then I could run the command : `rake db:setup`